# Modifying a query result to return a more usable array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, activerecord

Hey everyone,
I have a query result returned as an array with active record:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [name] => Betty Glassmaker ) 
[1] => Array ( [name] => John Johnson ) 
[2] => Array ( [name] => Bill Pratt ) 
)
```

But since my query specifically only asks for the name column, I would rather the results be modified to reflect this array structure:

```
Array (
[0] => Betty Glassmaker 
[2] => John Johnson 
[3] => Bill Pratt
)
```

What might be the easiest way to get the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through your array, something like this ( not tested )

```
// $resultset is you multidimensional array

$optimised = Array();  // good habit to initialise before usage.

foreach($resultset as $key => $value){
   $optimised[] = $value['name'];
}
```

Good-luck!

Comment: `$optimised = array();` Nothing wrong with initialize variables (indeed it's a very good habit), but initialize to a correct value for that variable.

Comment: Yeah. + oned for catching that.